# Unknown window pops up

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, 19.10

Twice in the last 24 hours, a strange window has suddenly popped up on my screen. It says "Hotspot login" on top, and just this one link. The name of the process is `gnome-shell-portal-helper`.

[image]

I don't need a portal helper, the wifi is working fine.

The link "check_network_status.txt" points to http://nmcheck.gnome.org/check_network_status.txt. Now you must be curious to know what happens when you click on it (I would be): it shows a web page with the text "NetworkManager is online".

What is the point of this window? Has anyone experienced this?

I'm on 19.10, Gnome shell version 3.34.1.

Edit: I notice that the window opens every time the computer wakes up from sleep.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the answer with the help of [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/419423/110698) from the Unix/Linux StackExchange.

Go to Settings/Privacy and turn off `Network connectivity checking`.

That's all.

Comment: Today I found out that another symptom of this setting is that the wifi symbol in the task bar may display a question mark, even though the wifi works fine otherwise.